# ASP.NET Web API 2 versioned routing with inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've been trying to implement versioned routing in Web API 2.2 (5.2.3) where a newer version of a controller has priority over previous versions when selecting an action for a specific route.

e.g. Given the following controller class hierarcy:

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers.V1 {
    public class FooController {
        protected IFooRepository Repo; // Assume Repo is injected via IoC

        [Route("{id:int:min(1)}")]
        public IFoo GetSingle(int id) {
            Repo.Single(new FooSearchOpts { Id = id });
        }

        public IEnumerable<IFoo> GetAll() {
            Repo.Search();
        }
    }
}

namespace MyApi.Controllers.V3 {
    public class FooController : V1.FooController {
        public IEnumerable<IFoo> Search(string type) {
            Repo.Search(new FooSearchOpts { Type = type });
        }
    }
}

namespace MyApi.Controllers.V4 {
    public class FooController : V3.FooController {
        public IEnumerable<IFoo> SearchV4(string type, string name) {
            Repo.Search(new FooSearchOpts {
                Type = type,
                Name = name
            });
        }
    }
}

namespace MyApi.Controllers.V5 {
    public class FooController : V4.FooController {
        /* nothing relevant */
    }
}
```

I can get some routes working by creating a custom `IHttpControllerSelector` that reads `{version}` from the route data (e.g. `GET /api/v*/foo/123` always points to `GetSingle`).

The problem appears when there are multiple possibles routes in different versions of the controller. I need the request `GET /api/v*/foo` to choose the following methods:

`/api/v1/foo` -> `V1.FooController.GetAll`
`/api/v2/foo` -> `V1.FooController.GetAll`
`/api/v3/foo` -> `V3.FooController.Search`
`/api/v4/foo` -> `V4.FooController.SearchV4`
`/api/v5/foo` -> `V5.FooController.SearchV4`

Just specifying a custom controller selector understandibly complains about duplicate/ambiguous actions, but I can't find any way to retain the existing action selection logic when I specify a custom `IHttpActionSelector`. Do I really need to reimplement all the method name parsing and parameter checking shenanigans by hand or is there a way to leverage the existing logic?

Unfortunately I can't post all of what I have already but the main routing config looks something like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // VersionedRouteProvider specifies a global route prefix of "api/v{version}/{ctrl}"
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new VersionedRouteProvider());

        // VersionedControllerSelector uses {version} and {ctrl} to map out controllers
        var controllerSelector = new VersionedControllerSelector(config);
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), controllerSelector);

        // VersionedActionSelector creates actions from controllers,
        // currently it would require iterating MethodInfos
        // and manually creating all HttpActionDescriptors
        // based on the methods' names and parameters
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new VersionedActionSelector(controllerSelector));
    }
}
```

I've looked into creating a custom `IDirectRouteProvider` and `IDirectRouteFactory` but it seems like I'd still need a custom `IHttpActionSelector` to handle ambiguous routes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Versioning should never work this way or you could disable all of your users code, as they will receive different results than they previously did. Versioning should be done with attribute routing (api/v2/whatever) to allow the consumers of your api to switch to the newer version as they choose.

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/v1/users")
public IHttpActionResult UsersVersion1() {}

[HttpGet, Route("api/v2/users")
public IHttpActionResult UsersVersion2() {}
```

Comment: The user still specifies the api version in the url explicitly, just as in your example, just the routing is based on namespace and class hierarchy instead of having to manually copy/paste potentially identical methods between versions and having to manually annotate everything with routing attributes.